# Ng-table filter issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

> How to filter the dynamic column data in ng-table ? 
>   the below filter have dynamic column name but filter not working

### filter="{ '{{searchFullQuote[tableColumns[0].header]}}': 'text' }"

Answer (score 0):

```
 <td ng-repeat="(field, value) in myArray[0]">
        <input type="text" ng-model="search[field]">
 </td>
```

As you didn't gave your working code.We can't get where you did mistake.
Here is working example https://plnkr.co/edit/KU2283t5nRjgz37NBQn5?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Alexa but i asked for Ng-table not a normal table